# How to create a crescent moon using bezier paths in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

How to draw a closed crescent moon using bezier paths, when the stroke and fill are configurable? So car I can get once curve but haven't found a strategy to connect and draw the other curve.

[image]

Comment: Update your question with what you have so far.

Comment: You need to use `addCurveToPoint` with appropriate values.

Answer (score 11):

If you want something better approximating an astronomically correct crescent (where the outer arc is 180 degrees), I might suggest something like:

```
CGFloat angle = M_PI_2 * 0.60;      // how much of a crescent do you want (must be less than M_PI_2 and greater than zero)

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:TRUE];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(center.x - radius * tan(angle), center.y) radius:radius / cosf(angle) startAngle:M_PI_2 - angle endAngle:angle - M_PI_2 clockwise:FALSE];
[path closePath];
```

That yields:

[image: result]

As you can see, the path is basically defined by two circular arcs, one clockwise, one counter clockwise. The specifics of the center, radius, and starting and ending angles of the inner arc is a matter of basic trigonometry (but the actual formulae will vary depending upon the precise desired look and feel). For example, in my code snippet, the `angle` in my code above is the blue angle in the following diagram, and I then calculate red triangle that will be used to determine the correct starting and ending angles and center for the inner arc.

[image: howto]

---

Below, someone asked about rotating this counter clockwise 90 degrees like:

[image]

In Swift, that would be:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -.pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y + radius * tan(angle)), radius: radius / cos(angle), startAngle: -angle, endAngle: -.pi + angle, clockwise: false)
path.close()
```

Comment: Hi @Rob I want to achieve this but in different angle. Check this image I want same like this. Please help me to achieve this.
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/6646/WzxysN.png

Comment: Just adjust the angles accordingly (and the for the second arc, move the center down rather than to the left). See expanded answer above.

Comment: Hi Rob, great code but how can I convert it to display a crescent with concave or inward curved part on top? I've tried few changes in your code but all resulted into something else.

Comment: Updated answer to illustrate this.

Comment: FWIW, if interested in example where you want to render single path of two arcs of two circles with different radii, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77871007/1271826. That is focusing on a specific problem (a series of crescent shapes with equal spacing between them, but the it outlines the basic math of using the law of cosines to figure out the starting and ending angles of the two arcs.

Answer (score 7):

The bezier path can be constructed from two arcs. In swift:

```
var big = UIBezierPath()
var angle: CGFloat = 5.0 // in radians
var rad  : CGFloat = 50.0
big.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), radius: rad, startAngle:-angle/2.0, endAngle: angle/2.0, clockwise: true)
big.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rad * cos(angle/2.0), 0.0), radius: rad * sin(angle/2.0), startAngle: 3.14/2.0, endAngle: -3.14/2.0, clockwise: false)
big.closePath()
```

Will create a path that when drawn will look like:

[image]

Edit: Objective-C with fill and stroke with upper left corner in x,y =  100,100):

```
UIBezierPath *big = [UIBezierPath new];
CGFloat angle = 5.0; // in radians
CGFloat rad   = 50.0;
CGFloat x=  100.0;
CGFloat y = 100.0;

[big addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x, y) radius:rad startAngle:-angle/2.0 endAngle:angle/2.0 clockwise:YES];

[big addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + rad * cos(angle/2.0), y) radius: rad * sin(angle/2.0) startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];


big.lineWidth = 2.0;
[[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
[[UIColor darkGrayColor] setStroke];

[big closePath];
[big fill];
[big stroke];
```

Comment: Where are the stroke and fill properties set? How do you set the radius for the inner circle - the one that is cut out? Also, I'd like to accept this answer but I've tagged the question as Objective-C. Thanks.

Comment: Swift and Objective-C have very direct API mappings (not so direct type mappings). Anyway, I included a Obj-C version with fill and stroke as you would use it in a context.  About the radius, the angle variable will change the small circle radious with meaningful values between 1.0 (large radius) and 6.0 (small radius).

Answer (score 0):

For complex shape drawing, I could suggest you a great application called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/).  With it, you can import vector graphics and get the associated path formatted in form of a bezierPath.  There is a trial available.  Here is what I got after converting your provided shape into a SVG file:

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(47.18, 5.32)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(67.96, 17.62) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(55.58, 7.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(61.06, 10.72)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(81.46, 49.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(77.56, 27.15) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(81.46, 36.45)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(67.96, 81.37) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(81.46, 62.55) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(77.56, 71.85)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(47.18, 93.67) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(61.06, 88.27) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(55.58, 91.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(24.98, 93.67) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(41.33, 95.17) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(30.83, 95.17)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(9.16, 86.32) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(19.81, 92.32) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(12.38, 88.87)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(7.06, 84.52)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(10.13, 80.47)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(19.13, 61.27) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(13.81, 75.52) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.01, 66.67)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(18.83, 38.25) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(20.33, 55.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(20.18, 43.42)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(9.98, 19.95) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(17.11, 31.57) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(14.03, 25.35)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(6.31, 15.07)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(8.78, 13.05)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(24.08, 5.55) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(12.16, 10.27) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(18.53, 7.12)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(47.18, 5.32) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(29.93, 3.82) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(41.11, 3.75)];
[bezierPath closePath];

self.shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
self.shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
self.shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 85, 98);
self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4;
self.shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];
```

The result:

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Why do you need more than two curves?

Comment: Because I barely converted OP's PNG into a SVG, then imported that SVG in PaintCode.  I can see at least two "straight lines" in OP's image (at the top & bottom).  Creating a similar shape in a vector graphic editor and transferring it directly into PaintCode would probably make a cleaner shape.  I had no such editor at hand to make an approximation of that shape.