# Creating Label like an Image in Objective C,iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

how can I create a label below like this image in iOS (Objective-c)?

[image: sample label]

My problem is not all corners, because I can round top-left & bottom-right corners by writing codes like this:

```c
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.customView.bounds
                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft
                                             cornerRadii:(CGSize){7.0, 7.0}].CGPath;
self.customLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and the result is this:
[image: my sample label]

Now how can I write codes for top-right & bottom-left to reach the goal?

Comment: what about setting an image to UIImageView and then using that as background ?

Comment: I can't use png file. because first time it was suppose to set this png in an imageView and the imageView becomes my labels background. but i faced a lot of problem like layout and adding constraints and some times the image width was bigger than label width. so i decide to delete the background images and just round the corners of my label. then faced a new problem. the problem is my label top-right & bottom-left

Comment: yeah , but you could use Resizable image , so it would only resize middle part , not rounded part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

I didn't use the height as a variable in my equations it may affect the results.

Better results

[image]

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat curveWidth = 40;
    CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;

//    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, curveWidth, 0, curveWidth};
//    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [fillColor setFill];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, height)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(curveWidth*2, 0) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(curveWidth*0.75, height) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(curveWidth*0.25, 0)];

    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(width-curveWidth*2, height) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(width-curveWidth*0.75, 0) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(width-curveWidth*0.25, height)];

    [path closePath];
    [path fill];

    [super drawRect: rect];
}
```

**Original Answer:**

I wrote the code for you. follow the steps:

[image]

1. Create a custom UILabel by subclassing it. (code below)
2. Add a UILabel to your view using interface builder.
3. Add your constraints.
4. In the Identifier inspector tab, change class to your.

--

```
@implementation CurvedLabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat curveWidth = 30;
    CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;

//    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, curveWidth, 0, curveWidth};
//    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [fillColor setFill];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, height)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(curveWidth*2, 0) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(curveWidth, height) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(width-curveWidth*2, height) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(width-curveWidth, 0) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(width, height)];

    [path closePath];
    [path fill];

    [super drawRect: rect];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks @hassan83.  your answer was correct. i was too late. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any simple way of doing that, you could use a png file, if that is not a option you should look in to UIBezierPath, check this link out: [ios drawing concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed it now.

Comment: By the way, there are automated ways to help you turning paths into code,  try looking here: http://ponderwell.net/2011/05/converting-svg-paths-to-objective-c-paths/ or here http://www.paintcodeapp.com/ if you are willing to pay for it....

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do it with a `UIBezierPath`. 
I have made a pretty simple setup you can use.

```
// This is the parallelogram's corner structure 
//    1------2
//   /      /
//  /      /
// 4------3 

 int xOffset = 150; // x Offset on the parent view - here self.view
    int yOffset = 50; // y Offset on the parent view - here self.view
    int flatten = 50; // The difference from center of curve to spike point (try to adjust it and see what it does)
    int width = 200; 
    int height = 100;

    UIBezierPath * maskLayer = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Start at corner 1
    [maskLayer moveToPoint: CGPointMake(xOffset+flatten, yOffset)];

    // Go to corner 2
    [maskLayer addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(xOffset+width+flatten, yOffset)];

    // Curve it down to corner 3
    [maskLayer addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(xOffset+width-flatten, height+yOffset) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(xOffset+width, yOffset) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(xOffset+width, height+yOffset)];

    // Go straight to corner 4
    [maskLayer addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(xOffset, height+yOffset)];

    // Curve it back to corner 1
    [maskLayer addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(xOffset+(2*flatten), yOffset)  controlPoint1:CGPointMake(xOffset+flatten, yOffset+height) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(xOffset+flatten, yOffset)];

    // Create the shape and fill it with a color 
    CAShapeLayer *maskShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskShapeLayer.path = maskLayer.CGPath;
    maskShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    // add the layer to a view's layer (here self.view.layer)
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:maskShapeLayer];
```

If you wanna make the two ´spikes´ more rounded, you can make the y-value in the `addCurveToPoint` points closer to the parallelogram's y-center-axis (height/2).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use`addCurveToPoint` of `UIBezierPath` to make it curvy by giving it `controlPoint1` and `controlPoint2`

For reference, you can look at [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

Also, this is a helpful [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084585/how-to-create-a-crescent-moon-using-bezier-paths-in-ios) too. 
You will have to play around with UIBezierPath's properties