# How can I make a transparent outline for circles so that the background shows through?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, layer, snapkit

How can I make a transparent outline for circles so that the background shows through? Like this:

[image]

I tried using a mask, but this code does not work ...

Perhaps there are some other solutions?

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background")
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImage)

        // Параметры для кругов
        let circleSize: CGFloat = 100 
        let borderWidth: CGFloat = 4 
        let circleSpacing: CGFloat = 30 

        var previousCircleView: UIImageView?

        for i in 0..<3 {
            let circleImageView = UIImageView()
            circleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ggg")
            circleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            view.addSubview(circleImageView)

            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleSize, height: circleSize))
            let borderPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: -borderWidth, y: -borderWidth, width: circleSize + 2 * borderWidth, height: circleSize + 2 * borderWidth))
            borderPath.append(circlePath)
            borderPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

            maskLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
            maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
            circleImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer

            circleImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.width.height.equalTo(circleSize + 2 * borderWidth)
                make.centerY.equalToSuperview()

                if let previous = previousCircleView {
                    make.left.equalTo(previous.snp.right).offset(-(circleSize - circleSpacing + borderWidth))
                } else {
                    make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
                }
            }

            previousCircleView = circleImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with masking shape layers. Can you upload your project to Github and add a link to your question? Also, is the image you posted your desired result?

Comment: my project: https://github.com/AlexDolm/testUI
the picture can be anything, the main thing is that the circles show through the background)

Comment: Those are not circles in the picture. One of them is a circle; the others are a sort of lunate shape. You will have to draw that lunate shape for each of them. As for the question of how to punch a hole in a view, that has been answered many times already. So it's just a question of doing that, but with the desired shapes and positions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice developer and may not understand something. I thought that in order to crop the circles as in the pictures, their outline must be transparent, only then the background will be visible. I can't think of any other way.

Comment: it seems that writing lunate shape is harder than outlining...

Comment: If the question is how to draw a lunate shape, that is what you should ask. How to cut a hole of a desired shape, if you can draw the shape, has been answered.

Comment: Are you trying to draw solid-colored circles with transparent rings around them, or image views? Your code is loading image views, then clipping and drawing a black border around them.

Comment: wow, this is very cool, thank you very much! I'll have to remember trigonometry)

Answer (score 1):

Each of those shapes is composed of two arcs. The only trick, requiring a little trigonometry, is to calculate the start and end angles for each. E.g., you can do something like:

```swift
func addSublayers(to view: UIView) {
    let radius: CGFloat = 150
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 10
    let circleCenterOffset: CGFloat = 120
    let startCenter = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)

    for i in 0..<3 {
        let shapeLayer = createShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circleDifference(
            center: point(startCenter, xOffset: CGFloat(i) * circleCenterOffset),
            radius: radius,
            offset: circleCenterOffset,
            width: borderWidth
        ).cgPath
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    let shapeLayer = createShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point(startCenter, xOffset: 3 * circleCenterOffset), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

private func point(_ point: CGPoint, xOffset: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    CGPoint(x: point.x + xOffset, y: point.y)
}

private func createShapeLayer() -> CAShapeLayer {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = …
    return shapeLayer
}

private func circleDifference(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let r1 = radius
    let r2 = radius + width
    let d = offset

    // angles; using law of cosines
    let angle1 = acos((r1 * r1 + d * d - r2 * r2) / (2 * r1 * d))
    let angle2 = acos((r2 * r2 + d * d - r1 * r1) / (2 * r2 * d))

    // path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: center,
        radius: r1,
        startAngle: angle1,
        endAngle: 2 * .pi - angle1,
        clockwise: true
    )
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: point(center, xOffset: offset),
        radius: r2,
        startAngle: 3 * .pi / 2 - (.pi / 2 - angle2),
        endAngle: .pi / 2 + (.pi / 2 - angle2),
        clockwise: false
    )
    path.close()
    return path
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

---

If you’re wondering about the trigonometry here, consider the following drawing, where the red (left) circle is the one to be rendered, subtracting the green (outer right) circle, which is the blue (inner right) circle, plus whatever spacing we wanted. To stroke the final path, we want to draw the leftmost arcs of the red and green circles, starting and stopping the arcs at the angles corresponding to where these circles intersect.

[image]

So, I imagined a triangle (shaded in blue), where the vertices are the centers of the two circles plus where the two circles intersect. The angles used when stroking the two arcs are this triangle’s bottom left and right angles. We know the lengths of all the sides of this triangle (the left side is the radius of the circle, the right side is the radius of the circle plus the spacing, and the bottom line is the distance between the circles).

In my original answer, I calculated the height of the triangle, *h,* the short vertical purple line segment (using a technique of dividing the area, calculated with [Heron’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), by the semiperimeter), and then calculated the two angles using `asin(h/r)`.

But I have revised my example to calculate the two angles via the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). This is simpler and will probably be more intuitive to most readers.

---

If all of this math is too confusing, you can just add each shape layer as a circle masked by another circle:

```swift
func addSublayers(to view: UIView) {
    let radius: CGFloat = 150
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 10
    let circleCenterOffset: CGFloat = 120
    let startCenter = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)

    for i in 0..<3 {
        let shapeLayer = createShapeLayer()
        var center = point(startCenter, xOffset: CGFloat(i) * circleCenterOffset)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        center = point(startCenter, xOffset: CGFloat(i + 1) * circleCenterOffset)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius + borderWidth, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
        mask.fillRule = .evenOdd
        mask.path = path.cgPath

        shapeLayer.mask = mask

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    let shapeLayer = createShapeLayer()
    let center = point(startCenter, xOffset: 3 * circleCenterOffset)
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Personally, I always lean towards creating the desired paths without any masks, but this latter approach completely avoids any confusing math.

Comment: Cool. I consider myself decent at trig, but I was struggling to figure out the math to find the starting and ending angles for the two arcs for each "crescent" / lunate shape. I had to Google Heron's formula. It lets you calculate the area of a triangle from the lengths of all the sides. How are you applying that to finding the starting/ending arc angles for the arcs that make up the shapes?

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I wish I could up-vote this answer by more than 1. A couple of minor things: you say "...the vertices are the centers of the two triangles plus where the two circles intersect". Don't you mean to say "...the vertices are the centers of the two **circles** plus the points where the two circles intersect"?

Comment: And, I am slightly red-green color-deficient (a fairly common problem) so I have a hard time making out the colors of your circles. You might want to use slightly thicker circles (I need a thicker line to make out colors), or refer to the left/right inner/outer circle for those who are fully colorblind.

Comment: Also, I didn't remember the law of cosines either. For those reading, "the law of cosines relates the lengths of the sides of a triangle to the cosine of one of its angles." See the Wiki article on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: Understood about not being able to (easily) change the graph. Thus my suggestion of referencing the circles by position rather than color. A significant minority of the population is color-deficient to one degree or another, so using color as the sole means of conveying information is not ideal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256674/discussion-between-rob-and-duncan-c).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is a series of crescents, ending in a full circle, creating a shape layer and a mask will involve drawing part-circle arcs, and some trig.

You could instead do this by creating an image view with the contents you want. In that case, you could write code that runs in a loop, drawing a circle in an opaque color, then switching to clear mode and erasing the outline of the circle. Each new circle will erase part of the previous circle, but the last circle won't be clipped. That's what your sample image shows.

Here is the code I wrote to create that image, loosely based on your starting code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
    
    
    // Install an image in imageView that contains a series of crescent shapes, ending in a full circle.
    private func setShades(count: Int) {
        var image = UIImage()
        let lineWidth = 7.0
        let circleDiameter = 50.0
        let width = CGFloat(count+1)/2.0 * circleDiameter
        let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: circleDiameter))
        let circleColor =  UIColor(_colorLiteralRed: 161.0/255, green: 62.0/255, blue: 3.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)
        image = renderer.image { context in
            for index in 0..<count {
                let x = CGFloat(index) * circleDiameter / 2
                let circleRect = CGRect(
                    x: x, y: 0,
                    width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter)
                let circle = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: circleRect)
                circle.lineWidth = lineWidth
                circleColor.setFill()
                context.cgContext.setBlendMode(.normal)
                
                //Fill the circle with our circle color
                circle.fill()
                
                //Switch the drawing mode to .clear, so we erase anything we draw
                context.cgContext.setBlendMode(.clear)
                
                // Erase the outline of this circle
                circle.stroke()
            }
        }
        // Place the image view near the bottom of the content view, and on the right side.
        let frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.maxX - bounds.width, y: view.bounds.maxY - 100 - bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        imageView.frame = frame
        imageView.image = image
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        // You need to create teh image view when the view changes its subviews
        //so that it is placed correctly (e.g. after device rotation)
        setShades(count: 4)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background")
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Here is a [sample project on Github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/LockingRings.git) that creates the image below:

[image]